# Universal App not opening

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm creating a Windows Universal App in XAML and C#.
I have 3 configurations:

1. Debug
2. Release
3. RELEASE_LIVE

I test it in local in all 3 configurations and the app works.
I create the packages in X86 with the option to "not create app bundle" and don't include PDF files and in the project configuration I UNCHECK the .Net native options.

I upload the package to a Package Flight and follow the normal submission process. The app approves the process. I download the app go to the

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
```

Folder and check that my app is listed there with the correct version.
I open the app from the store and nothing happens. Looks like not even the OnLaunched event code in App.xaml.cs is being run. It happens the same to some other colleges in the company.

I'm using this nuget packages:

- HockeySDK
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWIndowsPlatform
- Microsoft.NETNative.Analyzer
- MvvmlightLibs
- Newtosnfot.Json
- Rx-Main
- SQLite.Net-PCL

I'm targeting Windows 10586

I don't see any error, just the app don't even execute anything. Any ideas?

Regards.

Comment: I have no idea but have you check the event viewer?  "Event Viewer/ Windows Log / Application" contain the error events of win32 and uwp apps. Perhaps it may have the clue of your problem.

Comment: Is that convenient that you share your app's name so can we have a test? In the meantime, when package the app, it generate two packages, one for uploading and the other one is for sideload, could you please test sideload your package and see if the same problem happens?

Comment: Hi Grace, Thanks for the answer, currently If I use a package for the Package Flight it passes the certification, but If I upload it to the normal Store it  fails with this error:                                                                                     File clrcompression.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
File clrjit.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.                                            The app is not yet released so I cannot provide you with a link. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all the problem I had was without noticing it I updated the package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from 5.1.0 to 5.2.1. That was making all the submisions to the store to fail certification  so if you downgrade that package to 5.1.0 It's gonna be fine. There is a bug [already reported in the msdn.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cecb739-f41c-4449-9182-54c40e067652/uwp-submission-failed-with-error-code-1300-and-no-appxsym-file-inside-appxupload-package?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cecb739-f41c-4449-9182-54c40e067652/uwp-submission-failed-with-error-code-1300-and-no-appxsym-file-inside-appxupload-package?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cecb739-f41c-4449-9182-54c40e067652/uwp-submission-failed-with-error-code-1300-and-no-appxsym-file-inside-appxupload-package?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cecb739-f41c-4449-9182-54c40e067652/uwp-submission-failed-with-error-code-1300-and-no-appxsym-file-inside-appxupload-package?forum=wpdevelop) Thanks!